# PHP - Remember Selected value of Dropdownlist from mysql

Tags: java, php, mysql, session, cookies

I'd like to be able to remember the selected value of my dropdownlist.
Whether it be from java, a Session or Cookie and have it selected accordinaly after postback. Any help would be much appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
            <select name="Name" onChange="showSelected(this.value)">
                <?php 
                    $qRtu = "SELECT ID, Name From tblOption";
                    $result = mysql_query($qRtu);
                    while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                ?>
                <option value ="<?php echo $data['ID'] ?>" ><?php echo $data['Name'] ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put in the HTML to allow the form control to select a single selected option, something along the lines of:

```
<?php while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <option value ="<?php echo $data['ID'] ?>" <?php if($data['ID'] == 'some value') 
        echo( 'selected = "selected"' ); ?> >
        <?php echo $data['Name'] ?>
    </option>
<?php } ?>
```

The `'some_value'` is something that you will need to grab from your database, or session, or cookie, or whereever you plan to grab the default value of the select box from.

Comment: Thanks @watcher, that did the trick. Only problem I have is on initial load I get an undefined Index presumably cause I haven't selected anything as yet. What would be the best way to handle that? I'm fairly new at php pls excuse the simple questions. thanks again.

Comment: @user you can simply just add a check on the index such as: `if(isset($arr['index']))`

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working with the below.
    
    `<?php if(isset($_POST['Name']) &&       $data['ID'] == $_POST['Name'])`