# Getting stored multiple selected listbox with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

My scenario is a bit like the one in this thread:
[PHP - Remember Selected value of Dropdownlist from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189692/php-remember-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-from-mysql)

But my field has multiple values and I want to select these values according to the database onto the listbox selection.

I have a rough idea that I need to use a foreach loop (correct me if I'm wrong) and I need to use explode() the string for my multiple values in the field.

Let's say my form has listbox options "one, two, three, four, five" and this user has submitted the form with a listbox value of "one, two, three" only.

How do I retrieve and make the listbox hightlighted for options "one, two, three" and non-highlighted for options "four, five"?

Thanks in advance guys.

Here is my code that I've written so far:

HTML updating form with PHP:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table class="product_upload_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

<?php
    $select=mysql_query("select * from products_list where id='$id' "); 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){     
?>
<select name="product_category[]" id="category" size="5" multiple="multiple">

<option value="Available Stock">Available Stock</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
    <option value="New Arrival">New Arrival</option>
    <option value="Ruffles">Ruffles</option>
    <option value="White">White</option>
</select>
<?php 
}
?>

<div class="button"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"/></div>
</form>

</table>

<?php

$product_category = implode("\n", $_POST['product_category']);

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$update_product=mysql_query("update products_list set category='$product_category'");
}
?>
```

I'm not sure whether is this enough to understand. I have not started writing the PHP code onto the listbox as I do not know how to start.

Regards,
Jeff

Comment: Show us the code you've written so far. You need: 1) an HTML form 2) PHP code to process your form values 3) PHP code to connect to your database and store/update/read the information.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I retrieve and make the listbox hightlighted for options "one, two, three" and non-highlighted for options "four, five"?

```
$data = array('Available Stock', 'Black', 'New Arrival', 'Ruffles', 'White');
echo '<select name="data">;
foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo '<option value="'.htmlentities($value).'";
    if (isset($result[$id])) echo ' selected';
    echo '>'.$value.'</option>';
}
echo '</selected>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. May I ask if this getting the data from individual fields? Because I have a few values that is saved in 1 field in the database. =x

Comment: Hi, I've tried your code but it seems that it will select and display whatever values that is in the database.

Can I do the if else statement to add the "selected" options??

Comment: Hi Sergey, if I were to create let's say 5 options in the listbox and my database has already saved 3 selection that the user selected. Is there anyway to do like this?

<option value="new" "if else statement in here checking the $data from database, add selected="selected" if true"></option>

And repeatedly the same for other option. If I can do it this way, how do I break up the $data string with combination of different selected options into array form and put it in if else statement for checking? Hope you understand. =x

Comment: It's ok anyway, I've managed to work it out already thou I think it's quite a long and tedious way. Thanks guys. =)